# (Serious): Male genital protection for mountain biking/BMX and for common falls

Tags: protection

I want to start using a protection like a helmet for is for the head, but for my penis and testicles.

Why is important? It would give me much more confidence when triying new tricks and tecniques to not fear my genitals will be hurt, simply falling  in the wrong way could hurt me very bad.

I shouldn't worry? Well I do and maybe others don't, however I'm not neither the best biker that never falls, neither I think nobody should put others to that standard. If others don't want it ok, I need it.

Comment: Type "Genital protector" in google. Don't you get what you need?

Comment: Remember that the protection you use may impact on your comfort when riding in the saddle.

Comment: I'm not a mountain biker yet, but I remember when I was a boy the biggest perceived risk to my genitals was my feet slipping off the pedals, which could lead to my butt slipping off the seat and landing on the top tube.  If you're mountain biking on plain flat pedals then you might want to consider something that secures your feet to the pedals better, like SPD pedals and shoes with cleats.

Comment: On [travel.se], the idiom for titles is "OK, we're all adults here so..." :-)

Comment: In the 80s, the common solution was top tube pad, stem pad and handlebar pad. Since then it has been out that people don't hit their crotches against bike that often.

Comment: This also opens up the possibility for innovating/inventing a guard specifically designed for cyclists. Perhaps also re-thinking how the seat and top tube are designed.

Comment: The American term would be "cup", while "jock strap" would be the garment that holds it. I would imagine that Googling for "sports cup" or "jock strap" would get you what you're after. From there you can work out what the local terms would be. (I'm at work right now, so I'll not put that search in the admin's logs.) I'd imagine that you could pick up something at the local sporting goods store once you knew the correct terminology. As _Suspended User_ says in his(?) [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/44421/18643), though, it might not be comfortable for cycling use.

Comment: @rclocher3 there's worse things which can happen: landing with your butt on the rear tire while moving forward, resulting in your testicle(s) getting caught between tire and rimbrake parts. I won't go into more detail, but that's nasty. Anyway, SPDs and the likes for the style or riding the OP seems to be after will cause more harm than good in general due to not being able to get off the bike quickly enough in case of crashes or washing out.

Comment: For the rear wheel accident, most mud guards would offer a degree of protection. Even the (appropriately named) ass saver style would bend to hit the tyre and stop you getting pulled forwards.

Comment: I think the question here should be if that king of accidents actually happen.

Comment: While I can imagine some people wanting a cup, it would be less functional for me.  I use the tickle the rear tire generates on my man tenders to gauge when I'm far enough back for extreme braking.  No tickle?  Move farther back.  More firm than a tickle?  Too far back.

Comment: A dropper post would be the best solution for the mountain bike. Being able to lower the seat out of the way on downhill and technical sections gives the rider more room and confidence. No more smashing your chest or sacking yourself on the back of the seat.

Comment: Another jargon word is "box" which comes from Cricket.  Mostly used by batsmen and wicket keepers who are both in the path of the bowled ball,, not at all by fielders or bowlers who need to move and run.

Comment: I think back to all the various falls I have experienced, and the safety gear that has served the most is gloves and helmet.  I have never needed or missed a box, knee or elbow protectors,   Hip protectors could have saved me once too.     Low pressure clipless pedals are going to save you more often than anything else.

Comment: Yeah, one could use a "cup", but I have to believe that it would be incredibly unpleasant after an hour or two in the saddle.

Comment: There's a thing called the law of attraction. You get what you pay attention to. If you pay attention to crashing and crushing, that's what will happen. You don't see tricks skiers rehearsing how to crash before they kick off - they are rehearsing how to their tricks right. Focus.

Comment: Related question - do you wear a helmet on your head?

Answer (score 15):

Genital protection is rarely (if ever) used in cycling because it generally means putting some kind of hard surface in play (or excessive padding).  Either of these can easily lead to some very uncomfortable chaffing problems.  For less "pedalcentric" disciplines this might be acceptable (flatland, downhill, etc).  But, for the rest of the market there just isn't a benefit to loss ratio to justify it.

Many other sports have genital protection equipment that is used regularly.  Like winter cyclists who have to use mountaineering equipment to stay warm, you may have to dip into some other sports equipment cache to accomplish / try what you are suggesting.

Comment: +1 but, in the case I'm familiar with (cricket), protection is mainly against frontal blows, whereas cycling would require protection from below. Equipment designed for other sports definitely seems to be the most promising route but it might still not work out.

Comment: Baseball catchers often wear a "banana" style cup that provides some protection from below (missed catches can bounce up).  The style is also in use for MMA and some extend up to protect the lower abdomen as well.

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with that same question many years ago - and tried my share of products. The difficulty is that anything large or hard enough to provide any real protection is always incompatible with a bike seat and / or the natural position of the rider.

Plastic products hurt like hell when sitting on and push to one side or another. Too much padding causes numbness and discomfort.

About the best I've found are the padded lycra that roadies use - placed under my riding shorts. It doesn't provide total protection, but certainly helps.

Comment: Good close-fitting padded pants help a lot.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Criggie; Thank you, glad to be here. As much as I ride - I can't believe I just found this area of SO.

Comment: MTB riders (at least XC) use padded shorts as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try wearing a [jockstrap and cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jockstrap#Protective_cup), as is common in many other sports, but there's a good chance it'll prevent you from sitting properly on the saddle.  You can also try using the female version (called a "pelvic protector"), since those are made of foam rather than rigid plastic, and so might be better when you're pedaling.

You can also try swapping your bike seat for an [Infinity Bike Seat](https://www.infinitybikeseat.com/) to give room for the cup, but those seats are pretty expensive, currently starting at $170.